# How to reuse an array to write very fast to a big file in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to write  fast to a  big file and  using array. So I have to use same array multiple times. Part of my program is as follows.

```
    char buff[1024];
    char *x= buff;
    fd = open("file.txt",O_CREAT|O_RDWR, S_IRWXU) ;


    void function(){

        char temp[128];
        sprintf(temp,"%s,%s,%d\n",src,dst,payload) ;
        x=myStrCat(x,temp); // copy files from temp to buff

        //This is my question. if the buffer "buff" is full, how to  truncate the buffer for next loop and that too fast.
        if (strlen(buff) >= 1024){
            write(fd,buff, len);
        }
    }

    char * myStrCat(char * dest, char * src){
             while(*dest) dest++;
             while( *dest++ = *src++);
             return --dest;

     }

    int main(){
        //other codes
        while (true){        
            function();
            //conditions to break the loop untill then function() will be continuously in loop.
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is there something particular that doesn't work in your code?

Comment: `If (strlen(buff) >= 1024)`  is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: Yes sure.
I am trying to capture network traffic using libpcap tool. So for that I need to write captured packets to a file.  So in the below function in "temp" I can get the value of one packet at a time.
sprintf(temp,"%s,%s,%d\n",src,dst,payload) ;

Since my buffer ( buff[1024] )size is limited, so continuously my buff[1024] will be filled. Once it is full, I want to write the contents of my buff[1024] into a file. Then I want to reuse buff[1024] again for more packets to capture.

Comment: Do you want to write "veryfast" or do you want to write very fast?

Comment: @LPs `buff` and `x` seem to be global variables (at least seems so, looking at how `x` is used in `function()`), so filled with 0 and not UB.

Comment: I'm not getting you. Probably `buff[1024]` is the value of first byte of pointer `x`...

Comment: Am I reading this correctly that every time you concatenate something you are then doing a strcat that scans your buff starting from the beginning of buff in the first line of myStrCat? If so, then this approach is unnecessarily slow, probably by quite a bit. As is, you are appending up to 128 bytes at a time, so best case, before you write 1024 bytes, you are scanning 128 + 256 + 384 + 512 + ... + 896 = 3584, when you only need to scan 1024. The best answer probably depends on what size your input chunks are and how much that size can vary. Can you provide more detail on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for somwthing like this:

```
    #define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

char buff[BUFFER_SIZE];
uint16_t buff_len = 0;

void function(){

    char temp[128];
    int len = sprintf(temp,"%s,%s,%d\n",src,dst,payload) ;

    if ((len+buff_len) > BUFFER_SIZE-1)
    {
        write(fd,buff, buff_len);

        buff_len = 0;
    }


    strcpy(&buff[buff_len],temp); // copy files from temp to buff

    buff_len += len;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tested it and it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

`strlen(buf)` can never be >= 1024, since you only allocate 1024 bytes for it. C string requires a NULL to be in the end, so you will get a buffer overrun, which leads to undefined behaviour. You could have 1023+NULL, though.

Your code doesn't check if there will be a buffer overrun in the `myStrCat` either. It will cause undefined behaviour. What if you already have 1020 characters and want to add another 10?

The way you should do this is to keep a number indicating how many characters you already have in the buffer. If the buffer can't hold the next string, write the data into the file and zero the character count. If it can, copy the string to the buffer starting at the position indicated by the character count and get the next one.

Of course in the end write what's in the buffer to the file.

This way you will not run over the buffer limits.

(Are you sure this will be a lot faster than just letting the OS handle the write caching?)

Comment: Thanks for your input and  can you please add to that what should I do to reuse the same buff again and again in loop.
 I haven't compared thoroughly but I tried once and it was fast.

Comment: The **NUL** [character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) (`'\0'`) isn't the same thing as **NULL** (`((void *)0)`) which is a [pointer](http://c-faq.com/null/macro.html).

Comment: @mctylr Practically every document talks about null terminated strings and null characters, even though the character is really NUL. But good point still.